# In TFS, is it possible to create local workspace from a script?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

MS' [pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181384%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) talk about using the command-line `tf.exe` to create a local workspace prior to calling `tf get` but describe that even from the command-line, a TFS dialog box will be shown.

One of our build scripts, as we move from VSS to TFS, gets a repo into a working copy prior to building. It would be preferable if this script can be run on a 'clean' PC and it automatically creates the local workspaces, or can somehow get a copy without using a workspace (we really need something closer to svn export as no changes are being made). But a dialog box requires we manually set up each machine with local workspaces first.

Is what I want possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the full help `tf help workspace`, you see:

```
tf workspace /new [/noprompt] [/template:workspacename[;workspaceowner]]
             [/computer:computername] [/comment:("comment"|@commentfile)]
             [workspacename[;workspaceowner]]
             [/collection:TeamProjectCollectionUrl]
             [/permission:(Private|PublicLimited|Public)]
             [/login:username,[password]]
```

As you can see, you can specify `/noprompt` and all of the parameters that the prompt would collect.

For setting the working folder, you'd use `tf workfold`:

```
tf workfold /map serverfolder localfolder
            [/collection:TeamProjectCollectionUrl]
            [/workspace:workspacename]
            [/login:username,[password]]
```

Comment: I missed `/noprompt`, thanks. However is it possible to also set working dirs this way too?

Comment: @John `tf workfold` is your friend here. As above, try running `tf help workfold` to see the various options. And to see all of the available commands, just try `tf help`

Comment: A workspace created with "tf workspace /noprompt" is a server workspace (location=server). Could you add full example how to create a local workspace?